# Correspondence between a tree and a word (Cayley's theorem)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

So on the slides from a lecture from my university they try their best to explain the algorithm that matches a tree with n vertices to one of the n^(n-2) possible words. Here's the description they give:

```
(1) i <- 1.

(2) Among all leaves of the current tree let j be the least
one (i.e., its name is the least integer). Eliminate j and its
incident edge e from the tree. The ith letter of the word is
the other endpoint of e.

(3) If i = n – 2, stop.

(4) Increment i and go to step 2.
```

Then they give an example where the following tree:

[image]

yields the word 4164.

Could someone please explain in a different way how this algorithm works? I'm guessing it's pretty simple and straightforward but I don't get their explanation. Thanks

Comment: Read about  Prüfer sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say I re-write their algorithm as more code-like pseudocode:

```
for i from 1 to n - 2:
    j = min(leaves(T))
    word[i] = other(edge(j), j)
    remove(T, j)
```

where `other(edge, vertex)` gives the other end of an edge, and `leaves(tree)` gives the leaves of the tree, finally `remove(tree, vertex)` removes the vertex and any edges incident to it.

Then consider this table:

```
i      |1|2|3|4
j      |2|3|1|5
word(i)|4|1|6|4
```

Note that the tree (`T`) is altered at each step by removing the vertex `j` and then you use the other end of the edge in the word.